# javascript getelementbyid not working because id changed

Tags: javascript, asp.net

OK i want to get the value of a textbox but when i do the javascript code getElementByID() thing the id of the textbox changed from the original value how to i get it now??
I even tried putting the cliendIdMode="Static" didn't work.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function uploadFileChange() {
        var tbox = document.getElementById('txtFileName').value;
        var fu = document.getElementById("FileUpload1").value;
        if (tbox != fu) {
            document.getElementById('txtFileName').value = document.getElementById("FileUpload1").value;
        }
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

the orignal textbox was:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFileName" CssClass="textbox" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server"
                        Width="300px" ReadOnly="true" />
```

but then it became:

```
<input name="fuFileInfo$txtFileName" type="text" readonly="readonly" id="fuFileInfo_txtFileName" class="textbox" ClientIDMode="Static" onclick="fuFileInfo_FileUpload1.click();return false;" style="width:300px;" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ASP.NET renders the ID's differently to the server side markup.

Therefore use [`ClientID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to get the rendered ID:

```
var tbox = document.getElementById('<%=txtFileName.ClientID %>').value;
var fu = document.getElementById('<%=FileUpload1.ClientID %>').value;
```

Comment: is the '=' necessary in the <%=txtFileName.ClientID %>?

Comment: @JoaoSilva In short, yes. More information here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976112

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use jquery to get the value you can do

`var tbox = $("[id$='txtFileName']").val();`

what this will do is grab the element whose id ends with (thus the `$`) the id you are looking for.